# setLocale only works in method diffForHumans (carbon)

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to change months names    and the code I wrote

```
Carbon::setLocale( 'pt_BR' );
        $datetime = new Carbon('2016-01-23 11:53:20');
  $datetime->format('d/M/Y');
```

it should return  months names based on selected local

but it doesn't work   I get date like this

```
23/Jan/2016
```

it only work when I use  diffForHumans

is there any way to change the month name based on setLocale  ?

Comment: Add the code where you were using `diffForHumans` and it worked.

Comment: $datetime->format('d/M/Y')  change it to   $datetime->diffForHumans()   now it will work